# Name or algorithm for procedure to find the kth intersection of convex polygons.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, polygons

I am trying to determine the general name of something in Geometry/Computational Geometry.

If there are N convex polygons in R^2. Is there a name for the polygon(s) that result from the intersection of at least k < N of those polygons? Or if there is no name, is there a name for such an action or algorithm?

For example I have N=5 convex polygons on a plane and I want to find where say k=3 or more of them overlap, is there a name for that? I have attached a graphical example so you can see what I mean.

I have been calling it the k-intersection, but that does not seem to be standard.

Any help is appreciated.

[intersection of polygons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaKD9.png)

Comment: This feels quite specific so I'm not sure if there is a general algorithm. One tool that might be useful is the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function). It has a value of 1 for points in a set and is zero otherwise. If you create a function $h(x)$ that is the sum of indicator functions, one for each region, $h(x) = \mathbf{1}_A + \mathbf{1}_B + \ldots$ for regions $A, B, \ldots$ then you can define the sets you are interested in by $\{x : h(x) = N\}$ where $N = 0, 1, 2, \ldots$

Comment: You may want to have a look at "arrangements" from computational geometry. There are several existing algorithms to compute them in two dimension for various class of shapes. In your case, you could make one arrangement per polygon, label cells of the arrangement as "inside" or "outside, then overlay everything and check which cells has what label. Not sure if there's a name for a cell that belongs to $k$ polygons though. When dealing with lines, there's a name for a cell that is below $k$ lines I think.

Comment: Thanks PaulAljabar and @N.Bach

Those are good leads. The arrangements thing seems close but is not exactly what I am looking for. 

I have an algorithm that works, but its slow and seems "hacky" so I was hoping there was a name for this thing.